# Product of complex numbers goes to 0.

Tags: complex-analysis

Can someone help me with this assignment:

Let $\Re z <0$. Prove that $z_n=(1+z) \left(1+\frac{z}{2} \right) ... \left( 1+ \frac{z}{n} \right) \to 0$.

I was trying to look for a sequence $a_n$ which goes to $0$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$ such that 
$|z_n|^2 \le a_n$ but I've failed...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I've just managed it.
In each brackets in $|z_n|^2$ we have something less than $1$ for big $n$.

Comment: Less than $1$ isn't enough. You need $\lvert 1 + \frac{z}{n}\rvert$ to converge to $1$ slowly enough (or not at all, but it converges here).